# python node bad interpreter

Tags: rospy, roscpp, ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the c++ version is working but python shows the following :

rosrun hello_world talker.py

> /opt/ros/lunar/bin/rosrun:
> /home/kamal/catkin_ws/src/hello_world/script/talker.py:
> usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such
> file or directory
> /opt/ros/lunar/bin/rosrun: line 109:
> /home/kamal/catkin_ws/src/hello_world/script/talker.py:
> Success

this could be a noob doubt but i didnt get any working solution

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332534/python-node-bad-interpreter/) by [kamal_nathan](https://answers.ros.org/users/45487/kamal_nathan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2019-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first line of your python node tells the OS which interpreter to use to run it (in this case, python). I suspect you have a typo there; the first line should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kamal_nathan](https://answers.ros.org/users/45487/kamal_nathan/) on 2019-09-08**:
thank you for your reply
it works now , i had a typo on the shebang line.